# xsl copy-of with substring

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i have this function in xsl i took from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309746/how-to-convert-newline-into-br-with-xslt)

to replace "cr" with "line-break"

this is how i call it:

```
<xsl:variable name="breakText">
     <xsl:call-template name="insertBreaks"> 
          <xsl:with-param name="subject" select="PublicProfile/AboutMe"/> 
         </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
```

im doing like an article link to "read more" on text click
the first div of the short start of the article (550 chars of the long article)
display the text like i didnt use the "insertBreaks" function

```
<xsl:copy-of select="substring($breakText,0,550)"/>
```

but this line of the long description is working fine:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$breakText"/>
```

where i was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution used referred to in the question happens to be mine.

It replaces a newline character *not* with "line-break" but with a `<br />` *element*. An element is a node -- not a string.

Thus, the `$breakText` as defined in this question is a temporary tree (in XSLT 2.0) or an RTF (Result Tree Fragment) in XSLT 1.0 -- *not* a string.

**The problem is that** (regardless of an accompanying minor error of using zero as index):

```
substring($breakText,0,550)
```

**is a string (calculated from the *string value* of `$breakText`) and as such cannot include any `<br/>` element or any node at all**

**Remember**: The string value of an element or of a tree is the concatenation of the values of all of its text-node descendents.

**On the other side**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$breakText"/>
```

copies the temporary tree (in XSLT 2.0) or produces the serialization of the RTF (in XSLT 1.0).

To put it more simply, `xsl:copy-of` *preserves* structure, `string()` or any conversion to string produces just a string -- and a string doesn't have structure (all nodes are gone).

Comment: @roy.d: Please, edit the question and provide a complete (but as small as possible) example of an XML document, an XSLT transformation and the result you get, so that people could repro the problem -- then many people would be able to explain exactly what causes the unwanted output and provide a correct solution.

Comment: i edit the problame i have, the xml is not the issue also. i convert \r\n to <br> using function like i wrote above.

Comment: @roy.d: I edited my answer accordingly, explaining the difference between *copying* a node-set and converting it just to string. And this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: to solve it i call the function with parametes of substring text

Comment: @roy.d: I am glad my answer was useful.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `xsl:value-of` not `xsl:copy-of`. `xsl:copy-of` returns the elements and all their values of the selected tag. `xsl:value-of` returns the text associated with the selected tag. Since you're trying to get a substring, you want the text.

Comment: `$breakText` likely points to an element. You can do `copy-of` on an element. You can't do `substring` on an element though, only its text, and you certainly can't do `copy-of` on the resulting string.

Comment: how can i show the text after i replaced what i want in both cases substring and full?