# Preserving line break from Java to HTML

Tags: java, html-encode

We use a XSL transformation to emit HTML. The XSL template for transforming a `message` node is as follows:

```
<xsl:if test="Message/text() and not(Message/text()='')">
   <tr>
      <td style="font-size:14">
         <b>
           <xsl:value-of select="Message/text()"/>
         </b>
      </td>
   </tr>
</xsl:if>
```

The Message emitted by java code is in the following format (illustration):

```
Update of Key 1 failed becasue...  
Update of Key 2 failed becasue...  
Update of Key 3 failed becasue...
```

(Each failure followed by a line break).

How can I display this data with line breaks on the resulting HTML? At present, it swallows the line breaks.

Comment: you can't add `<p>` or `<br>`?

Comment: You can translate newlines to the html br tag , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309746/how-to-convert-newline-into-br-with-xslt

Comment: If I add <br/> to the text before feedign to the the XSL,it gets emitted as is  - instead of being interpreted as a line break in html.

Comment: With Java's support for HTML, you may need to use the `<br>` tag instead of `<br/>`.

Comment: Use CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space