# How to transform XML newline to HTML br via XSL?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to transform a newline (\n) from my XML document to a 'br' tag in HTML via XSL without adding extra tags.

**Example:**

```
<item name="Test">
    <title>Test</title>
    <text>
        <p>Hello
        World</p>
    </text>
</item>
```

After the Hello is the newline -> '\n'.

**What i want:**

```
<article>
    <p>Hello<br>World</p>
</article>
```

**What i tried (not working):**

```
<xsl:template match="\n">
    <br>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </br>
</xsl:template>
```

Is this possible without adding extra tags ?

Comment: Can you say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Check out this question then, as it should contain the solution you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309746/how-to-convert-newline-into-br-with-xslt

Answer (score 0):

Below code can produce the result as you wanted in XSLT 1.0

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <article>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/*"/>
   </article>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
<p>
<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="not(contains(., '&#xA;'))">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '&#xA;')"/>
       <br/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are assuming there will be at most one newline character in the processed text. I see no basis for such assumption.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I just did only on the basis of input and not considered as general case. If he needs he should mention in the question. Anyway I will use recursive to process the text.