# force line break in xml displayed in html using xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, sms, newline

must preserve line breaks in sms messages. must be viewable in web browser. please help. my goal is to open "sms.xml" in browser and see "line1" and "line2" (from message body) on separate lines

i have two files:

sms.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sms.xsl"?>
<smses count="1" backup_set="b8123816-3935-4dee-9705-4b484ebe0582" backup_date="1486606490878">
  <sms protocol="0" address="0123456789" date="0000000000000" type="2" subject="null" body="line1&#10;line2" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="0" readable_date="Aug 19, 1949 10:53:27 AM" contact_name="anonymous" />
</smses>
```

sms.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body{
                        font-family:arial,sans-serif;
                        color:#000;
                        font-size:13px;
                        color:#333;
                    }
                    table{
                        font-size:1em;
                        margin:0 0 1em;
                        border-collapse:collapse;
                        border-width:0;
                        empty-cells:show;
                    }
                    td,th{
                        border:1px solid #ccc;
                        padding:6px 12px;
                        text-align:left;
                        vertical-align:top;
                        background-color:inherit;
                    }
                    th{
                        background-color:#dee8f1;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>SMS &amp; MMS Messages</h2>
                <table>
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width:80px"/>
                        <col style="width:120px"/>
                        <col style="width:120px"/>
                        <col style="width:180px"/>
                    </colgroup>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="smses/*">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="name() = 'sms'">
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:if test="@type = 1">Received</xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="@type = 2">Sent</xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="@type = 3">Draft</xsl:if>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:if test="@msg_box = 1">Received</xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="@msg_box = 2">Sent</xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="@msg_box = 3">Draft</xsl:if>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@address"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@contact_name"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@readable_date"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="name() = 'sms'">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@body"/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="parts/part">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="@ct = 'application/smil'">
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="@ct = 'text/plain'">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="@text"/><br/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="starts-with(@ct,'image/')" >
                                                    <img height="300">
                                                        <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(concat('data:',@ct), concat(';base64,',@data))"/>
                                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                                    </img><br/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                    <i>Preview of <xsl:value-of select="@ct"/> not supported.</i><br/>
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you are doing the transformation in the browser, you are restricted to XSLT 1.0. In this case, check out this question, which shows you how to replace `&#10;` with a `<br />` tag in XSLT 1.0. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309746/how-to-convert-newline-into-br-with-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in xslt 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@body, '&#10;')">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><br/></xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="@body"/>
```

Comment: tokenize function is used in xslt 2.0, change your xslt version at top

Comment: great! I am wondering why such a modern and elegant answer is hard to find. I wish I could upvote more.